# RCurl default proxy settings

Tags: r, curl, proxy, rcurl

I'm working here behind proxy so I need to configure my connection.
It works well with defining options list and calling getURL:

```
opts <- list(
  proxy         = "http://****",
  proxyusername = "****", 
  proxypassword = "*****", 
  proxyport     = ****
)
getURL("http://stackoverflow.com", .opts = opts)
```

I'd like to set this options as defaults, but still cannot find any working solutions. Could you advise anything?

Thank you.

Comment: You could explicitly create a curl handle (`getCurlHandle`) and then call `curlSetOpt` on that object, and use that as a parameter to all your get calls via the `curl=` parameter.

Comment: It looks like you also may be able to set an option with `options(RCurlOptions = list())` but I have not tried that myself. Just put all your values in that list.

Comment: Yes, MrFlick, options() works perfectly as I found yesterday

Answer (score 5):

I regret to hurry up posting question.
The solution was really at the hand, at RCurl FAQ page.
There is an option **RCurlOptions** which can be defined at the Rprofile.site file of R

But I'm still in trouble because RGoogleAnalytics library seems to overwrite this.

For completeness, here is the code:

```
opts <- list(
  proxy         = "http://****",
  proxyusername = "****", 
  proxypassword = "*****", 
  proxyport     = ****
)

options(RCurlOptions = opts)

getURL("http://stackoverflow.com")
```