# Proxies and httr vs RCurl

Tags: r, rcurl, httr, ropensci

Has anyone heard of problems using `RCurl` vs. `httr` when the user is using a proxy?

I have this package [taxize](https://github.com/ropensci/taxize) in which some functions use `RCurl` and some use `httr`. A user reports two functions that don't require her to pass in proxy details, and those two functions use `RCurl` internally. While some functions that don't work without proxy auth details passed in use `httr`. In all cases, these are GET requests.

Is it possible that `RCurl` somehow handles the proxy without her having to pass in her proxy username, password, etc., while `httr` requires them? If so, why would that be?

[This gist](https://gist.github.com/sckott/23a96219629942bbe476) has examples of 2 functions that apparently require proxy auth details and 2 that don't.

Comment: Did you maybe set [default proxy settings for RCurl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25120043/rcurl-default-proxy-settings) and not for `httr` in the session?

Comment: Thanks @MrFlick One of my users is the one behind the proxy, not me. She said she had to pass in proxy auth details for fxns that use `httr` internally, but not to those fxns that use `RCurl`.

Comment: Given that httr calls RCurl eventually, it's hard to imagine why there should be any difference.

Comment: @hadley I agree!  I don't understand either. Perhaps I'll move everything to `httr` so that at least that eliminates variation due to internal curl processes

Comment: RCurl supports auth settings, which you can view and change with `options(RCurlOptions = list(proxy="gateway:port", proxyuserpwd="user:password"...`. I know you're saying that your user does not have to specify authentication settings with RCurl so to answer this, I searched the source code on GitHub and verified it on my own machine - the default proxy option is NULL. Either auth settings are being grabbed from outside of R or they were set at some earlier point. You can verify this by running the getOption command above. Let us know the result.

Comment: Any updates? I'm having a similar issue where if I set the RCurl proxy options and use RCurl they are utilized, however when I use httr they are not utilized.

Comment: :: update:: I've found you can pass the httr option with use_proxy.

Comment: @variable what does that look like

Answer (score 3):

On Windows, I had to unset my environment proxy settings to successfully use httr

```
Sys.unsetenv("http_proxy")
```

Comment: Thanks for that.  I'll see if that can help at all