# How to check if an url object is reachable or not using try catch in R

Tags: r, try-catch, fread

I have the following URL objects and need to check if they are reachable before downloading and processing the CSV files. I can't use the URLs directly as it keeps on changing based on previous steps.

My requirement is, read the link if reachable else throw an error and go to the next link.

```
url1= "https://s3.mydata.csv"
url2="https://s4.mydata.csv"
url3="https://s5.mydata.csv"  

(Below code will be repeated for the other 2 URLs as well)

readUrl <- function(url1) {
  out <- tryCatch(
    {
readLines(con=url, warn=FALSE)
error=function(cond) {
            message(cond)
      
      return(NA)
    },
finally={
      
      dataread=data.table::fread(url1, sep = ",", header= TRUE,verbose = T, 
                            fill =TRUE,skip = 2 )
    }
  )    
  return(out)
}

y <- lapply(urls, readUrl)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not the function `url.exists` directly from package `RCurl`.

From documentation:

> This functions is analogous to file.exists and determines whether a
> request for a specific URL responds without error.

Function doc [LINK](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RCurl/versions/1.98-1.2/topics/url.exists)

Using the boolean result of this function you can easly adapt your starting code without Try Catch.

Comment: But I can't explicitly give the URL links as it changes dynamically. Will an object assigned to an URL can also be used for url.exists function?

Comment: Yes, you can pass a variable, which dynamically has assigned an URL, to the function

Comment: I tried the below code, but for both the URLs it gives me FALSE as output(i.e url is not reachable ). 


url_exists <- function(x) url.exists(as.character(x))

abc="https://s9.filedata.com/inventory/2020_feb.csv"
xyz="https://s9.filedata.com/inventory/2020_jan.csv"

df=data.frame('urls', c("abc","xyz"))

df_exist <- mutate(df, exist = sapply(urls, url_exists))

Comment: Maybe is a proxy problem like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40391047/why-url-exists-returns-false-when-the-url-does-exists-using-rcurl